# Использование ширины экрана в условном оператора

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно сделать, чтобы при ширине экрана меньше `1025px` пользователя перекидывало на другую страницу. Если меньше - вставлялся `<iframe>` на текущую страницу.

Написал, но условие не работает:

```
if (window.location.href == "такая-то ссылка").innerWidth < 1025 {
    $('.container').append('<iframe src="какой-то iframe"></iframe >');
} else {
    window.location = "на определенную страницу";
}
```

Как правильно написать эту строку: `if (window.location.href == "такая-то ссылка").innerWidth < 1025`?

Comment: `при маштабе экрана менше 1025px, ..., если меньше, ...` А что делать если больше?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Синтаксис вашего условия не правильный. Наверно вы хотите так:

```
if(window.location.href === "такая-то ссылка" && window.innerWidth < 1025) {
    $('.container').append('<iframe src="какой-то iframe"></iframe >');
} else {
    window.location = "на определенную страницу";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так работает:

```
if (window.location.href == "такая-то ссылка") {
    $('.container').append('<iframe src="какой-то iframe"></iframe >');
    if ($(window).width() < 1025) {
        window.location = "ссылка на другую страницу";
    }
}
```

Comment: Какой смысл добавлять `<iframe>` при ширине меньше 1025?